# how to remove border line in custom uiview?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2

[image]

I made a custom view and I called it in UINavigationController, I made it transparent but after I put it inside navigation controller I got that border, how to remove it? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide some code of your custom view implementation

Comment: can you try by setting border color?

Comment: `customView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor()`

Comment: I did by setting border colour but still the same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to set border width of your view with 0

```
yourView.layer.borderWidth = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the border color of your view transparent.

```
yourview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

This should work.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it still the same @Sandro

Comment: Hum, can you try to add a pixel to your view in the top and in the bottom? Are you sure that is the view that is displaying the border? Try to use the [view debugging](https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6) to validate that is the view that is adding the border. That code should remove the border.

Answer (score 1):

**Update on Swift 3+**

```
yourview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out. (91,158,236) is the color of your navigation bar.

```
yourview.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 91.0 / 255, green: 158.0 / 255, blue: 236.0 / 255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
```

For a red View contained in navigation Bar for a borderWidth of 4.0 it would produce result like

[image]

Hope this helps.